# Why does this crash the compiler?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have this code:

```
var nodeMap:Map[Int, List[Node]] = Map[Int, List[Node]]()

nodeMap = Map[Int, List[Node]]() ++ nodes.par.groupBy( x => x.getClosest(centers))
```

x.getClosest returns an Int. When I go to compile this, the compiler crashes saying it's out of memory. However, when I do this:

```
var nodeMap:Map[Int, List[Node]] = Map[Int, List[Node]]()

nodeMap = nodes.groupBy( x => x.getClosest(centers))
```

It works fine.

Why?

Comment: because there's a bug in the compiler.  what kind of answer are you looking for?  i suggest you find the appropriate place and report the problem.

Comment: I was hoping for a work around and perhaps an explanation of why it happens (if it's not a compiler code but something in the implementation).

Comment: The compiler shouldn't run out of memory. It's not actually running the thing. As for workarounds, I'd use the `toMap` method (which is better anyway), or if you insist on vars, `nodeMap ++=`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Scala compiler has some issues with complex expressions; if you ran out of memory proper (i.e. OutOfMemoryException) it's likely a bug, however it is more often the case that the compiler runs out of stack space, in which case you can add the flag `-Xss=256m` (where the number is obviously up to you) to work around the problem. This is particularly common with complex expressions (string and list concatenations, for example).

Comment: `256m` of stack space is a bit... extreme. `3m` has sufficed for me even in the most extreme situations.

Comment: I believe it's a maximum, and yeah, it's definitely extreme. I have run into cases (with the Scala compiler specifically) where even 128m wasn't enough for some expressions, though. Likely the numbers differ between architectures, 32- and 64-bit etc.